# Angular: click method on file input in async function does not open file selection prompt in firefox

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox

EDIT: Checkout this stackblitz in Firefox and change the delay from 2000 to 1000 and back, you'll see what i mean: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3kvx7q

So this is kinda strange. I've got a hidden file input which is programmatically clicked after the user has selected the source (This PC | The software's file storage) via a dialog.

This would be the component's template:

```
      <button mat-stroked-button color="accent" (click)="c()">{{buttonLabel}}</button>
      <input hidden
             type="file"
             #fileUploadInput
             multiple>
```

This is the method that does the thing:

```
@ViewChild('fileUploadInput') fileUploadInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

    async c() {
        // Prompt the user to select source
        const source = await this._s.promptUserToChooseFileSelectorSource().toPromise();
        if (source != null) {
            switch (source) {
                case 'LOCAL_FILE_SYSTEM':
                    // Click file input
                    this.fileUploadInput.nativeElement.click();
                    break;
                case 'FILE_STORAGE':
                    // Select from file storage
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

In Chrome this is working as expected but Firefox simply does not show the systems file selection prompt.
So i've fiddled around a bit and tried just to trigger it directly:

```
@ViewChild('fileUploadInput') fileUploadInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

    c() {
        this.fileUploadInput.nativeElement.click();
    }
```

Which is working. I'm kinda lost, what am I missing here?

Another example which does not work in FF:

```
    c() {
        this._s.promptUserToChooseFileSelectorSource().subscribe(() => {
            this.fileUploadInput.nativeElement.click();
        })
    }
```

Well this is really strange.

This is working in FF:

```
    c() {
        new Observable(subscriber => {
            setTimeout(() => subscriber.next(), 1000);
        }).subscribe(() => {
            this.fileUploadInput.nativeElement.click();
        });
    }
```

But the same thing with a longer delay is not:

```
    c() {
        new Observable(subscriber => {
            setTimeout(() => subscriber.next(), 2000);
        }).subscribe(() => {
            this.fileUploadInput.nativeElement.click();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler if you instead placed a placeholder under (with some custom styling) and the actual input over it with 0 opacity?

Comment: Well this would not save my problem since i first display a dialog to the user where he can choose the file source. If the user chooses "This PC" the dialog closes and the file prompt is opened

Comment: Fair enough. Works for me though - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cfabaq (even if I hide the input or implement delay). I think the problem may be Firefox not awaiting the promise properly. Try adding an `else` statement and log out some testing text just to see if Firefox reaches it.

Comment: `if (source != null)` bothers me. What if Chrome returns `null` but FF returns another falsy value like `undefined`? I think you can remove this line altogether, it's useles, because there's already a `switch` statement underneath.

Comment: Good point. But i debugged and it reaches the .click() in FF but still no file selector. I added another, simpler example.

Comment: Take a look at my latest example, it appears to be connected with the delay somehow. I am confused